# DIY linear servo mechanism?

Tags: servo, stepper-motor, motion

This might belong on the new Makers site, but it could be applicable here too.

I'd like to position a device on a **1 meter** linear shaft to within 50 microns.  I can currently, with steppers, get down to 20 microns but I have all the disadvantages of steppers.  However, I have the awesome upside of steppers, in that I'm spending about $50 total (more like $200 for 4 steppers, but still).  Being DIY, budget is pretty important, as is not increasing the mass of the device on the shaft by more than a couple dozen grams.

I don't know the best way to approach this.

1. linear encoder strip of some manner
2. optical encoder on brushed DC motors and limit switches at 0m and 1m
3. stick with steppers

Comment: "LVDT" is less than 15 characters so I have added this sentence. More ...

Comment: what specific downsides of steppers bother you?  If cost is important, it sure seems tough to beat steppers.  With servos, you still need your motion controller chipset, and hobbyist stuff is still going to cost you $30-$60 per axis.  A really nice rotary encoder will set you back another $50.  Linear encoders are big bucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is a Linear Variable Differential Transformer or, in this case, probably a series of them.

LVDTs are usually only used over distances of say 100mm so you need 10 x that. And linearity is often only in the order of 0.1% with care and worse with less care.
BUT resolution is theoretically infinite - limited by the measurement system.
So, to work you would probably want multiple triple-coil systems, and you would have to calibrate it overall in absolute terms - probably with calibration data in memory and compared against measurements, due to the linearity constraints.
But it should be possible to build a system that had both resolution and accuracy as good as your measurement system. Breaking it up into multiple sections relieves the requisite resolution of measurement.

20 microns in 100mm = 1:5000 = about 13 bits so a 16 bit measurement should suffice.

Steppers start to sound attractive :-).

Just to open the mental filters, here is a report describing a 20 nm resolution in about 20mm system using LVDT. LASER INTERFEROMETER GRAVITATIONAL WAVE OBSERVATORY [The Linear Variable Differential Transformer position sensor
for Gravitational Wave Interferometer low-frequency controls.](http://www.ligo.caltech.edu/docs/P/P010035-00.pdf) - "not your average application".
Note the writer's comment below - note the only 1% linearity but 10 nm resolution. You may be wanting to avoid lock-in amplifiers :-)

- By a careful choice of the coil geometry it was possible to get better than one
  percent linearity over 25 mm of movement range with less than a percent sensitivity to
  transversal movements.  Also the sophisticated design of the lock in amplifier circuit
  allowed for better than 10 nm r.m.s. position resolution over the afore mentioned range.

[**And here is an excellent DIY article**](http://www.mikesflightdeck.com/lvdts/lvdts.html) - several oders of magnitude above instructables level.

[Some real products](http://www.macrosensors.com/lvdt_core_connecting_rods.html) - nothing over about 50mm :-(

---

LVDT basic operation:

[From here](http://www.sensorland.com/HowPage006.html)

- Two components comprise the LVDT: the mobile armature and the outer transformer windings. The secondary coils are series-opposed; wound in series but in opposite directions.

  When the moving armature is centered between the two series-opposed secondaries, equal magnetic flux couples into both secondaries and the voltage induced in one half of the secondary winding is balanced and 180 degrees out-of-phase with, the voltage induced in the other half of the secondary winding.

[image]

---

**Animation:**

The diagrams below are a screenshot of a 'Flash'animation - worth watching if a feel is wanted of how voltages vary with position [From here](http://www.rdpe.com/displacement/lvdt/lvdt-principles.htm)

[image]

Comment: I once looked into LVDTs for position feedback, and they seemed really great, but the signal conditioning modules were about $200, which will probably blow the OP's budget.  Unless he knows how to do it himself (which is possible since this is the electronics forum! wonder why I am even here...haha)

Comment: LVDTs seem perfect.  My linear rod is ferromagnetic.  Wonder if I can DIY one of them...

Answer (score 2):

The rotary encoders for linear gantries will ruin your 20 microns (You possibly are mistaking the stepping resolution to absolute positional accuracy). Rotary encoders can only be used for velocity feedback loop. Positional reading should always use tape.

For 0.1..1.0 microns reading use those expensive invar tapes with envelopes, glue, reader heads and homing markers. Do not use limit switches as homing reference.

Well, the cost of good 1 micron tape based setup for linear motion can cost $1K.
I do not defend the greed of monopolists in motion industry, but what you can possibly do ? If you can build your own lab with tapes, rubies, optometry, granite tables etc, then you may reach the cost of below $1K per gantry after few years of trying. But who wants to try it ? There is no shortcuts, unless you can live with very very slow motion.

For very very slow motion you can invent tons of solutions with capacitive readers like on calipers, induction readers like in scales, even some cheap laser interferometer etc. But this is every time a self serving science, which is impossible to reuse.

One thought about cheap tape is using cheap microscope camera reading a unique pattern on long tape with search algorythm based on calibration against reference tape. But this will require massively fast CPU and gigabytes of memory. Which means slow, again. Every normal motion needs a response in microsecond or less.

Comment: why do you say that rotary encoders will ruin his resolution requirement?  why can rotary encoders only be used for velocity feedback?  I'm surprised because you can use a leadscrew or belt to get linear motion, and rotary encoders are just fine for position feedback.

Comment: That is what I mean exactly. You can build linear with leadscrew and some fancy zero-backlash loaded nut. But it will be worse than 20 micron for sure. If you compensate backlash in software, the setup will work until first small kick (small mechanical shock, and you need recalibrate again, do homing etc.). Best leadscrew accuracy with rotary reading I could achieve on very expensive setup was much worse than 20 micron (may be 100 micron at best). And it was about 70 cm travel, not even 100cm. You may possibly beat it, but it will be much more than $20 you started with.

Comment: The fundamental problem with rotary encoders is that they're relative, not absolute. You need an absolute distance measure to avoid the constant recalibration.